# WPML Dropdown Issue, how to alter its HTML structure?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am using WPML for multiple languages on my WordPress website, but I am having a problem with the mobile menu. As soon as I open the dropdown menu, I am redirected to the URL.

As you can see in the photo I shared below, there is a URL in the `<li><a href="URL">` tag. This is exactly the problem. I want to make this URL "#" or I want to remove the `<a>` tag completely but I don't know where to do this. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Tolga

I haven't used WordPress much before, so I don't know which file to interfere with and where to do it. The solution to the problem in HTML is simple, but I don't know where and how to do it with WordPress.

[image: Screenshot of WPML language selector's HTML code]